# Can javascript generated from Kotlin sources be used back in JVM?

Tags: kotlin

Is it possible to use js generated from Kotlin sources in JVM to manipulate java objects and its own js objects?
Kinda create dynamic environment for development in distributed environment.
So new versions of classes can be dynamically loaded/modified on running remote servers while development. And then after it's done release versions to be compiled statically for max performance.
How hard would it be to implement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current implementation of Kotlin does not have any support for invoking Java methods from JS-generated code. This could in theory be accomplished using Nashorn, but we (the Kotlin team) do not currently have any plans to work on that. If you're interested, you're welcome to contribute, but this would be a fairly long and difficult project.